# How to use variables set in a sub called in a FOR loop, with delayed expansion

Tags: loops, variables, batch-file

This code loops through the contents of "Fire" folder on PC, which contains several subfolders. For each subfolder it runs another FOR to look for a match to directories on a tablet. If no match found it calls subroutine :missing to set variables about the missing directory.

When I get back to main routine I'm unable to echo the vars set in the sub. I've tried many permutations of !name[%CNT%]! (doubling/tripling the % and !) but can't get it right. Hope someone can lend a hand.

```
@Echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
:main
Set /A CNT=0
    :: Fire folder contains dirs that may have been deleted from tablet. 
    For /F %%G IN ('dir /b %Fire%') DO (
        SET thisdir=%%G
        SET /A CNT+=1
            :: set command that will look for %%G on the tablet
            set cmd="adb shell ls /system/priv-app/!thisdir!"

            :: This loop returns nul if dir exists on device
            For /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%g in ('!cmd!') do (set _N=%%h)
            If NOT "!_N!"=="" call :missing !thisdir! 

                    :: HERE'S THE PROBLEM: With this syntax I get    "CNT"     "CNT"
                    Echo AFTER THE CALL:        "!name[!CNT!]!"     "!pkg[!CNT!]!"

                    :: this displays:   "pkg[3]]
                    Echo AFTER THE CALL:        "%!name[!CNT!]%!"     [!pkg[!CNT!]!]
    )

:missing
:: Both %CNT% and !CNT! work here
    Set pkg[%CNT%]=%1

:: set friendly name for this dir
If "%1"=="com.name.video" set "name[%CNT%]=Video"
If "%1"=="com.name.games" set "name[%CNT%]=Games"
. . .
    :: THIS WORKS HERE IN THE SUB. HOW TO DISPLAY IN MAIN?                      
    Echo MISSING:       !name[%CNT%]!     (!pkg[%CNT%]!)

    :: Output: MISSING:          Video      (com.name.video)
exit /b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display in main loop:

```
call Echo AFTER THE CALL:  "%%name[!CNT!]%%"     [%%pkg[!CNT!]%%]
```

Iassume you know not to use `::comments` in a block and that your maun will run into your sub...

Answer (score 1):

In your first `AFTER THE CALL` line, your script will try to evaluate `!name[!` and then a string literal `CNT` and then `!]!` and so on.  Since both `!name[!` and `!]!` are undefined, they evaluate to nothing and you're left with the string literal, `CNT`.  Instead, you should convert the inner `!CNT!` to percent notation, so it can peacefully coexist with the outer delayed variable.  You can accomplish this with a `for` loop.

```
for %%I in ("!CNT!") do echo !name[%%~I]!
```

... to avoid the conflicting exclamation marks.  In your second `AFTER THE CALL` line, you attempt to begin a variable with `%!` while also ending it with `%!`.  When using that sort of syntax, the `!` has to be outside, and the `%` inside (or possibly vice-versa -- see [Magoo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34669774/1683264) for an example). But since it's inside a parenthetical code block, it won't work like you want anyway.  You need the delayed expansions.  Use the `for` loop I described above.

By the way, don't use those `::` pseudo-labels as comments within a parenthetical code block.  Use `rem` instead.  The `::` can break things.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
@echo off&SetLocal EnableDelayEdexpansion

set "name[1]=something"
set "a=1"

echo !name[%a%]!
rem echo %name[!a!]%
call echo !name[%a%]!
call echo %%name[!a!]%%
call echo %%name[%a%]%%
for %%a in (!a!) do (echo !name[%%a]!)

pause
```